# SQLAlchemy join only one column

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have following models defined:

```
class Attribute(Base):
    __tablename__ = "attributes"

    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True, index=True)
    data_id = Column(BigInteger, ForeignKey("data.art_no"))
    name = Column(VARCHAR(500), index=True)

    data = relationship("Data", back_populates="attributes")


class Data(Base):
    __tablename__ = "data"

    art_no = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True, index=True)
    multiplier = Column(Float)

    attributes = relationship("Attribute", back_populates="data", cascade="all, delete, delete-orphan")
```

If I query for a `Data` object, I get this for attributes:

```
[<app.db.models.Attribute object at 0x10d755d30>]
```

But I want to get:

```
['attribute name X']
```

What I want to get is, that the attributes field should be an array of the `Attribute.name` fields of the `join`'ed attributes.

My current query is:

```
db.query(models.Data).all()
```

How do I need to modify my query so the `attributes` field of `Data` contains not `Attribute` objects but just the strings `name` of `Attributes?

I hope you understand the question well ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`db.query(models.Data).all()` returns an array of `Data` objects. So you can define a custom property on the `Data` class to extract names from attributes relationship:

```
class Attribute(Base):
    __tablename__ = "attributes"

    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True, index=True)
    data_id = Column(BigInteger, ForeignKey("data.art_no"))
    name = Column(VARCHAR(500), index=True)

    data = relationship("Data", back_populates="attributes_rel")


class Data(Base):
    __tablename__ = "data"

    art_no = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True, index=True)
    multiplier = Column(Float)

    attributes_rel = relationship("Attribute", back_populates="data", cascade="all, delete, delete-orphan")
    
    @property
    def attributes(self):
        return [attribute.name for attribute in self.attributes_rel]
```

Note that by default sqlalchemy will fetch `attributes_rel` for each `Data` object separately upon access. This might result in N+1 selects problem. To avoid that you should specify [relationship loading technique](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/loading_relationships.html)

Also take a look at [with_entities](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.with_entities) and [hybrid attributes](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/hybrid.html?highlight=hybrid_property)